# Store and retrieve variables from objects

Tags: ruby

I want to store and retrieve some variables from object. For example in `a`

```
a = "a"
```

So far I found two possible ways to do it.

- Using `instance_variable_set` and `instance_variable_get`

  ```
  a.instance_variable_set(:@x, 10)
  a.instance_variable_get(:@x) # => 10
  ```
- or just using `instance_eval`

  ```
  a.instance_eval { @y = 5 }
  a.instance_eval { @y } # => 5
  ```

The second approach looks shorter and simpler for me, is there anything wrong with my code if I prefer this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speed isn't everything, but... the `instance_variable_set` method is faster than using `instance_eval`. Here's a benchmark if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/1268188

Here's another post that gives another good reason for avoiding `instance_eval` when possible: [Alex Kliuchnikau on instance_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038663/1177119)

Comment: Good answer! +1. Also, one of the other reasons is security.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no good reason (e.g. metaprogramming), you'd better avoid using instance_variable_get(set), coz it will **break encapsulation**.  You can refer to ruby-doc: thereby frustrating the efforts of the class’s author to attempt to provide proper encapsulation.

And the best practice of using instance_eval is to compose DSL style:

assume you have a Engineer class with instance method: program, play and sleep.  So,

```
sb = Engineer.new

sb.program
sb.play
sb.sleep

# is equivalent to
sb.instance_eval do
  program
  play
  sleep
end
```

In this case, it's shorter :)

Comment: In general, if there is an accessor provided by the class, just use plain getter and setter is better (at least never a bad idea).