# test loop return value in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I need to test a method which is as below

```
class Something
  def test_method
   count = 0
   arr = []
   max = 500
    puts "test_method"
    loop do
      arr += count if count.even?
      count += 1
    end break if count > max
    return arr
  end
end
```

So basically I need to test whether test_method() return an instance of array and arr size is greater than 3.
But I dont want to enter into this loop for every time and return the result. So is there any way in rspec where I can stub the max value and return the array without looping 500 times.

Comment: Pass `max` as an argument.

Comment: I dont want to edit the method (test_method) which is written. So without that is there any way??

Comment: No, not the way this method is written. `max` is "hard-coded" and you can't stub local variables.

Comment: BTW, your method doesn't actually run. `arr += count` won't work and `break` is outside your `loop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`class_variable_set`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_variable_set) method.

```
class Something
  @@max = 500

  def test_method
   count = 0
   arr = []

    puts "test_method"
    loop do
      arr += count if count.even?
      count += 1
    end break if count > @@max
    return arr
  end
end
```

In your case, an `rspec` `before_each` block could look like this:

```
before(:each) { Something.class_variable_set :@@max, 20 }
```

You can use an `instance_variable` too, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038623/326543)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is an option to pass `max` as a optional argument to that method?

```
class Something
  def test_method(max = 500)
    count = 0
    arr = []
    puts "test_method"
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: without passing max as argument, is there any way to achieve it??

Comment: THe thing is max arugment is set inside this test_method. So it cannot be hardcoded since We will not know in advance value of max

Comment: If you call that method without an argument (`test_method`) then `max` will be `500` like in your example. But if you want to run test will smaller `max` values, you can call the method with an argument (e.g. `test_method(5)`). Beside that: No, you cannot change a local variable that is assigned in a method from a spec. It must be defined outside of the method.

Comment: @rubyist *"We will not know in advance value of max"* could you explain that? In your code, `max` is set to `500`.

Comment: That is just a pseudo code.. My original code is like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776782/rspec-testing-the-return-value-after-looping

Comment: @rubyist you're already stubbing the JSON request, just set a lower value in `sample.json` and your method will use that value.

Comment: Yes.. I see that.. Great.. I was not knowing the actual use of stub method. I am just learning Rspec while experimenting.. Thanks a lot